# Different menu Items for different roles

Tags: asp.net, roles

I have a custom Login Page where i authenticate users from DB. In return i get if the user is authenticated and also if the Role of the User.
**e.g., User belongs to Role X, Role Y or Role Z**

I wanted to show different menu items depending on the role of the user.
Does the sitemap file help in this situation.since it does have the Roles Attribute
But how should i pass the info to the next page that the user belongs to this Role. I am building the sitemap like this....

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
   <siteMapNode url="" title="Top" description="" roles="*">
      <siteMapNode url="GeneralUser.aspx" title="General User" description="" roles="GeneralUser" />
      <siteMapNode url="PowerUser.aspx" title="Power User" description="" roles="X" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: you can bind menu in each page load, or can also save the menu in session any way you are comfortable..

Comment: Yes this of-course an option to have different sitemaps for different roles and then dependning on the role bind it. But i was wondering we can set the role in Page Load and the rest a sitemap will care of.What u say?

Comment: I am not talking about having different sitemap for each role you can have just i sitemap and use MenuItemDataBound event while binding to hide unwanted items.

Comment: Hmm @Ratna is this possible what i am saying in previous set the role in Page_Init() and then the rest will the site map take care of

Answer (score 0):

you can add to each user in the database table a list of allowed urls and main menu items they can view and allowed to access and when you get the role of each user then you keep it in session variables , then you show and hide items in the site1.master as follows :

```
             //--------- Hiding Menu Items ------------------------
                for (int i = Menu1.Items.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--)
                {
                    if (Session["AllowedMenus"].ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf(Menu1.Items[i].Text.ToUpper().ToString()) < 0)
                    { 
                        //---- Hiding Main Menu
                        Menu1.Items[i].Text = "";
                        Menu1.Items[i].Enabled = false;


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int j = Menu1.Items[i].ChildItems.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                        {
                            url=Menu1.Items[i].ChildItems[j].NavigateUrl.ToUpper().ToString();
                            //---- Hiding Submenus
                            if (Session["AllowedURLs"].ToString().ToUpper().IndexOf(Menu1.Items[i].ChildItems[j].NavigateUrl.ToUpper().ToString()) < 0)
                            {
                                Menu1.Items[i].ChildItems[j].Text = "";

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```